# Using the data mapper pattern

Tags: php, datamapper

If I have a User, and a UserMapper.  Would I hash the password outside the class, set the hashed password on the User set method and then save the User with the UserMapper, or would I implement the Hash method to the User (data holder) class and then save with UserMapper. Or lastly, would I Hash in the save() method in the UserMapper? What is the correct way when implementing the Data mapper pattern?

Here's the User data holder:

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    protected $id;

    public function __construct($row = null) {
    if (!is_null($row)) {
        $this->id = $row['id'];
    }
    }

    public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
    }
```

Comment: Depends on your preference. I would say, hashing outside the class is wrong. But the other patterns seems more or less identical. I do the hashing in model set method...

Comment: Yes, that seems like the right choice, but then I would need to inject the Hash class which gets me suspicious about it...